# Rgd: How to pass unsigned char*&

Tags: c++

```
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void rc4(unsigned char * ByteInput, unsigned char * pwd,
    unsigned char * &ByteOutput){
    unsigned char * temp;
    int i,j=0,t,tmp,tmp2,s[256], k[256];
    for (tmp=0;tmp<256;tmp++){
        s[tmp]=tmp;
        k[tmp]=pwd[(tmp % strlen((char *)pwd))];
    }
    for (i=0;i<256;i++){
        j = (j + s[i] + k[i]) % 256;
        tmp=s[i];
        s[i]=s[j];
        s[j]=tmp;
    }
    temp = new unsigned char [ (int)strlen((char *)ByteInput) + 1 ] ;
    i=j=0;
    for (tmp=0;tmp<(int)strlen((char *)ByteInput);tmp++){
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + s[i]) % 256;
        tmp2=s[i];
        s[i]=s[j];
        s[j]=tmp2;
        t = (s[i] + s[j]) % 256;
        if (s[t]==ByteInput[tmp])
            temp[tmp]=ByteInput[tmp];
        else
            temp[tmp]=s[t]^ByteInput[tmp];
    }
    temp[tmp]=' ';
    ByteOutput=temp;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char data[256] = "hello";
    unsigned char pwd[256] = "2147124912";
    unsigned char output[256];
    rc4(data,pwd,*output); 

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
meme@ubuntu:~/CSCI368$ g++ try.cpp -o try
try.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
try.cpp:42:20: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘unsigned char*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘unsigned char*’
try.cpp:5:6: error: in passing argument 3 of ‘void rc4(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*&)’
```

I am trying to compile but I think my argument 3 got problem `rc4(data,pwd,*output);`

How do I pass as `unsigned char*&`

Comment: Use `std::string` and your life will be much easier

Comment: "How to pass unsigned char*&" - in a well-formatted way, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned char* output;
rc4(data,pwd,output);
```

not

```
unsigned char output[256];
rc4(data,pwd,*output);
```

But like the comments above say, why use pointers when you don't understand pointers? This code could be written more simply and with fewer bugs by using `std::string` and/or `std::vector`.

Comment: How do i do it with string n vector. i found this rc4 encryption code at some site.. I can't test the output also. not sure what i did wrong

Comment: If you don't know pointers and you don't know vectors then I think you should start by learning a bit of C++. Like lots of code on the internet the code you found is quite low quality (in fact it looks bugged to me). wikipedia has a good looking description http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4 I suggest you write your own version from that description, using arrays or vectors or strings whatever you feel most comfortable with. It will be a good learning exercise for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

That example of yours is far from minimal, please reduce your code before posting. Anyway, the point is that an array is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element when passed to a function. Assuming this code:

```
void f(unsigned char*);
unsigned char array[100];
f(array);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
void f(unsigned char*);
unsigned char array[100];
unsigned char* ptr = &array[0];
f(ptr);
```

The point is that when passing a reference, you imply that the reference could be modified. This pointer here is an unnamed temporary created by the compiler though, so any modifications to it will be lost. For that reason, this conversion is forbidden, which is what the error is all about.

You don't want to pass an array but a real, non-temporary pointer. Also, you want to use `delete[]` on it when done. However, as others pointed out, using containers like vector or string are much cleaner ways. Get a good C++ book, these things should be explained there!